# Intermittent Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed:HTTP: Failured: url

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

We have a Flex application that sometimes throws this error **Intermittent Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed:HTTP: Failured: url 'http://nsmjboss:8400/backbone/messagebroker/amf'**

I can hit that link in a brewer and it works fine, and I don't see any errors in our logs. 
My services-config.xml

```
<flex-client>
    <timeout-minutes>120</timeout-minutes>
</flex-client>

<channels>  
    <channel-definition id="backbone-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
          <properties>
            <connect-timeout-seconds>480</connect-timeout-seconds>
        </properties>           
    </channel-definition>       

    <channel-definition id="backbone-streaming-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamingamf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>

    <channel-definition id="backbone-polling-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
            <polling-interval-seconds>4</polling-interval-seconds>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deactvating the proxy on your browser and see is the problem is solved.
See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158394/flex-random-netconnection-call-failed-http-failed).