# flex : Random NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed

Tags: apache-flex, websphere, amf, netconnection

We are experiencing some random **NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed** when using the flex 4 **mx.messaging.channels::SecureAMFChannel**

We have never had this problem in our local servers (server/client on the same machine), but when we went live, some users experienced this problem randomely (about 5% of the 800 beta users).

Lately, at last i was able to reproduce the problem every once in a while on *one client* machine (windows XP), in our LAN using a remote server in the same LAN (but not on other client machines who share the same LAN and are roughly the same configuration).

And when this happens:

- Using firebug / flashbug : I can see that the amf request is sent and waiting for a response.
- On the server there is nothing in the logs (no request received).
- After some timeout, the client shows the above error (**http code 404**).
- Then for the subsequent requests, everything returns to normal untill the error  eventually happens again

(Clients are Windows XP, Firefox + adobe flash player, Server is WebSphere 7)

My questions are: 
is there a way to find out what's going on ? 
is it a packet loss ? 
is it because of the client browser / adobe player ?

Thank you

[Edit]

Using Wireshark (on both the client and server side), i can see that when the problem occurs no tcp connection is made:
 - Firebug detects an outgoing http amf request 
 - Wireshark doesn't detect any activity on either side.

So it's defenitly Adobe Flash Plugin / Firefox plugin container, am i right ? is that a known issue ?

Comment: Can you check the network traffic at a lower level? Both client and server? Something like Wireshark.

Comment: @dbreaux i managed to run wireshark as you suggested and edited the post. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the proxy parameters of our browser resolved the problem ("No Proxy" instade of "Automatic detection" or "system proxy").

It looks like Adobe Flash plugin gets lost when a proxy is selected.